# how to extract rows in a big table based on a list file containing the specific names in linux

Tags: linux, unix, grep, row, extract

I have a really big data table (DataTable.txt), a snapshot as below:

```
SNPname chr position sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 ....sample2000
rs1 1 1000 A A B B ..... A
rs2 2 1500 B A B A ..... B
rs3 3 1503 B B A A ..... A
.
.
.
.
rs99999 22 999999 A A A ...... B
```

And I have a list of SNPnames that I want to include in my output table (other SNPnames not in this list will be excluded). The list (list.txt) is as below:

```
rs4560
rs4780
rs6
rs798
rs2634
rs987
rs1839
rs3948
rs2423
rs232
```

How can I produce a new output table that contains only the SNPnames listed in the list file?

Please advise, thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example this:

```
grep -wFf list.txt DataTable.txt
```

- `-w` matches words.
- `-f` gets the patterns from the file `list.txt`.
- `-F` compares the strings as such, not as possible regular expressions.

Based on your sample input, and changing `rs3` to `rs6` to have a match, this what I get:

```
$ grep -wFf list.txt DataTable.txt
rs6 3 1503 B B A A ..... A
```

Comment: hi fedorqui. sorry it was a really big file so it took me the whole day to finish the process. yes it works, but somehow the first row which has the labels for each column was not extracted together. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi @user3446084 , well it was not extracted because it does not match in the `list.txt`. You can either add the `SNPname chr position sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 ....sample2000` line in `list.txt` and process again, or just append it to your result file. You can find some nice ways in the thread [How do I add text to the beginning of a file in Bash?](http://superuser.com/q/246837/204979) For example `sed -i '1iSNPname chr position sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 ....sample2000' file` makes it.

Comment: if I were to add the SNPname chr position sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 ....sample2000 line in list.txt and process it again, will it retain its table matrix?

Comment: It really depends on your file, but it should. But if it took you one day to process all the grep, I think it is best to just add the header with `sed` as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: happy easter holiday! thanks so much fedorqui! you really helped a lot! :) god bless you

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
grep -Fwf list.txt bigtable.txt
```